# SOA WCF vs Web APi vs Odata

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am designing a SOA application that has clients WPF - Desktop for Windows Authentication , Mobile(iOS,Android, Windows 8.. and son) , Web Browser - Mobile and web building with Asp.net MVC5 along with OAuth2.

What is the best service to architect WCF Rest or  WCF OData or  Web API or Web API Odata , which has high performance response time  , unit testable and with all CRUD, Filtering, Grouping , Authorization, Authentication and fast to development time.

Also framework must support Active directory, OWin/Oauth2 and Individual authetnication (registration as in MVC5 SPA)

Thanks,
ineffable

Comment: If you are going to use only in web app use `WebAPI` or go with `WCF with REST` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer WCF Data Services, which use the Open Data Protocol (OData), to web service enable a repository for CRUD operations.  The development is relatively straightforward and the resulting architecture is clean and efficient.

Refer to the following post for additional discussion of the benefits/preferences of each approach: [SOA WCF vs Web APi vs Odata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247276/soa-wcf-vs-web-api-vs-odata).

Regarding OAuth, WCF Data Services supports claims-based authentication, which can be extended to provide support for OAuth 2.0.  The following links provide additional information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728284(v=vs.110).aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2011/01/20/oauth-2-0-and-odata-protecting-an-odata-service-using-oauth-2-0.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2011/01/21/connecting-to-an-oauth-2-0-protected-odata-service.aspx

Also, I recommend the following video by Scott Hanselman which provides an informative and fun discussion of OData.
http://app.looplogic.com/azgroups/odata-begins

Comment: WCF Odata vs WebApI Odata  also does WCF Odata support Oauth2 authentication

Comment: I updated the answer to address WCF OData support for OAuth 2.0.

Comment: What is the advantage of using Wcf Odata vs Web Api Odata

Comment: @ineffable about you last question, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504023/wcf-data-services-odata-vs-asp-net-web-api